# Limit the number of viewscoped beans saved in session in JSF

Tags: performance, jsf, heap-memory, jsf-2.3

I'm using JSF 2.3 with javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD set on client but viewscoped beans are still saved in session and after page reloading the beans are not garbage collected.

I've read about parameters com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession and com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews but it looks like this only applies to server state saving.

How can I avoid this and destroy the beans that are not used?